# UIScrollView in UIView: detecting scroll programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I got a UIView containing an outlet to a UIScrollView.

I would like to detect when the view scroll.

This is my code:

```
// interface
@interface MyView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
-(void)setup;

// implementation
@implementation MyView    
@synthesize scrollView;

-(void)setup {
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 160)];

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(30, 160)];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    scrollView.bounces = false;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true;

    [self addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
}
```

What am I missing? Do I need to modify the storyboard to activate "scrollViewDidScroll"? Can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Set the scrollview's delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the delegate of scrollView during setup:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```